# Select element based on attributes-Some elements missing

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, attributes

I have data on XML where the app is trying to elect the appropriate node programmatically based on attributes.

Here is the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CoagAlgo>
    <AlgoName
        name="Algo1"
        state="1.1"
        references="test1">
        <titletext>Title1</titletext>
        <optText
            selectState="1.2">opt1</optText>
        <optText
            selectState="1.3">opt2</optText>
    </AlgoName>
    <AlgoName
        name="Algo1"
        state="1.2"
        references="text2">
        <titletext>Title2</titletext>
        <optText
            selectState="1.2.1">opt12</optText>
        <optText
            selectState="1.2.2">opt13</optText>
    </AlgoName>
    <AlgoName
        name="Algo2"
        state="1.1"
        references="text2">
        <titletext>Title21</titletext>
        <optText
            selectstate="2.1">opt21</optText>
        <optText
            selectstate="2.2">opt22</optText>
    </AlgoName>
</CoagAlgo>
```

Here is the part of the code;

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String algoName1="Algo1";
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String stringXMLContect = null;
        try {
            XmlPullParser parser=(XmlPullParser)xmlParserIni();
            stringXMLContect= getTitle(parser,algoName1,"1.2");

        }catch (XmlPullParserException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TextView myText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myText.setText(stringXMLContect);
        RadioGroup radioGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.mainGroup);

        ArrayList<String> optChoices=new ArrayList<String>();
        try{
            XmlPullParser parser=(XmlPullParser)xmlParserIni();
            optChoices=optTextReader(parser,algoName1,"1.1");
        }catch (XmlPullParserException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i=0;i<optChoices.size();i++){
            RadioButton radioButton=new RadioButton(this);
            radioButton.setText(optChoices.get(i));
            radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
        }

    }

    private XmlPullParser xmlParserIni() throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    Context context = this.getApplicationContext();

    XmlPullParser xmlResourceParser = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.optchoices);
    xmlResourceParser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES,true);
    return xmlResourceParser;
}
    private String getTitle(XmlPullParser xmlResourceParser, String algoName,String algoState)throws XmlPullParserException,IOException{
        String attrValue = "";
        int eventType=0;
        while (xmlResourceParser.next()!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            eventType=xmlResourceParser.getEventType();
            String algoRootName=xmlResourceParser.getName();
            switch (eventType){
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if(algoRootName!= null && algoRootName.equalsIgnoreCase("AlgoName")){
                        String algoCompName=xmlResourceParser.getAttributeValue(null,"name");
                        String algoCompState=xmlResourceParser.getAttributeValue(null,"state");
                        if(algoCompName!=null && algoCompName.equalsIgnoreCase(algoName)&& algoCompState!=null && algoCompState.equalsIgnoreCase(algoState)){

                                xmlResourceParser.next();
                                if (xmlResourceParser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                                    attrValue = xmlResourceParser.getText();
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    break;

            }
            xmlResourceParser.next();
    }

        return attrValue;
    }
```

This should return the title text on the based on the name and state attribute of each AlgoName element. If the name is equal to the given text the title should be returned. If I give name as Algo1 and state as 1.1, I get the correct title. If I give name as Algo1 and state as 1.2 I get blank. When I debug, I can see that Algo1, state1.1 is passed to but the parser seem to skip the second part and directly goto title element of Algo1, state 1.2. Please help me understand what is happenning.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line 'xmlResourceParser.next();' 4 lines from the end of file.